# Changes to bindinglist don't update entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Consider the following:

**a** is an entity.

```
var x = from a in b select a;

var y = new BindingList<a>(x.ToList());
myListbox.Datasource = y;
```

When I do a remove on **y** and then **a.SaveChanges()**, the changes don't seem to be save in the database.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm sorry if my example isn't very clear, but I'm fairly new to all this.

Cheers!

Comment: Exactly what change do you expect to occur to `a` when you remove it from `y`?

Comment: I expect the changes made in **y** (ie: the removal of an element) to be reflected in **a**.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Removing an item from `y` is a change to `y`, not `a`.  What effect do you expect that to have on `a`?  Removing an egg from a carton has no effect on the egg.

Comment: I'm sorry, my impression was that 'y' is a bound list consisting of a list of items returned from the query 'x' which is a query executed on 'a'.  So that's why I expected a change in 'y' to be reflected in 'a'.

Comment: The query is executed on `b`, not `a`.  I'm afraid that your hypothetical is just plain bad and you STILL have not explained exactly what change you expect to see.  `a` is a single item.  What do you expect to change in that single item by removing it from `y`?  If you don't know then I think that explains why you don't see what you expect, i.e. you have no actual expectation.